# JQuery: Create an array made out of the data- attributes of my select options

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select multiple with some options. 
Each option has multiple data- attributes.
I would like to create an array that contains each of its data- values.
For example my code looks a lot like this:

```
<select multiple id='my_select'>
<option data-my_id='1' data-my_parent='3' data-my_name='option1'>My first option</option>
<option data-my_id='2' data-my_parent='3' data-my_name='option2'>My second option</option>
<option data-my_id='3' data-my_parent='3' data-my_name='option3'>My third option</option>
</select>
```

And the result I am looking for needs to be something like this:

```
[1,3,option1], [2,3,option2], [3,3,option3]
```

I have researched how to create an array with one of the data- attribute value for each of the options, giving me this [1,2,3], but I have been unsuccessful in coming up with what I need.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
var array = $("#my_select > option").map(function() {
    return [$.map($(this).data(), function(v) {
        return v;
    })];
}).get();
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/nQ6mE/

Comment: is it possible to apply addClass on this array

Answer (score 8):

```
var arr = [];
$('#my_select option').each(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  arr.push([ $this.data('my_id'), $this.data('my_parent'), $this.data('my_name') ]);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response! This works great, too! I like @VisioN 's answer a bit better because I am able to get ALL the data attributes  without having to do $this.data('value') for every single one.

Comment: This is not the answer to the question